# Django - Using input variables in other functions

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to find a good way to use user-provided variables later. I've stripped it down to this minimal example:

models.py

```py
class Input(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()

class InputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Input
```

views.py

```py
def input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/results')
    else:
        form = InputForm()

    return render_to_response('input.html', 
        {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def result(request):
    # Here I would like to get the input from the form, e.g.
    #
    # x = request.GET["x"]
    #
    # or
    #
    # inp = InputForm(request.GET)
    # x = inp.x
    #
    # Something like this, so that I can be able to write the line below:
    return HttpResponse("x = %f" % x)
```

What is the recommended way to do this?

EDIT:

The main problem seems to be that the request.GET dict is empty in the results function, i.e.

```py
def results(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.GET)
```

shows only an empty page. And then of course request.GET['x'] gives the exception "Key 'x' not found in QueryDict: {}". My input.html looks like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Compute" />
</form>
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to send request.GET back to InputForm, like in FallenAngel's original answer, but it does not work because request.GET is empty.

Comment: `<form method="post"` so you must use `request.POST` not `request.GET`

Comment: I tried using request.POST, but I still get the same problem; x is not a key. And the debug page says Request Method: GET. How should the input.html file ideally look like?

Comment: You may remove `{% csrf_token %}` from your html and test. May be you may have some misconfiguration in there. Also check your url configuraion. Be sure everything is right in ther etoo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I do not misunderstand you, you want to use value of a  field of a posted form without saving. You can use `commit=False`, so, it will only create an object using the Meta Model, but will not save it to your database:

```
def result(request):
    inp = InputForm(request.GET)
    if inp.is_valid():
        my_obj = inp.save(commit=False) # do not save it to database
        return HttpResponse("x = %f" % my_obj.x)
```

UPDATE: If you do not need form validation (for some reasons), you can use dictionary methods since `request.POST` and `request.GET` are dictionary-like objects. ([Request GET and POST objects in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET)). So:

```
request.GET['x']
```

or

```
request.GET.get('x')
```

will work for you.

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I was looking for. I want to do some calculations, so no need to store the input variables in a database. The problem is that the line inp.is_valid() returns False in any case, even though the input is just an integer.

Comment: The problem seems to be that request.GET is empty, I have edited the main question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/sessions/) to hold values from one view to the next. Sessions have many backends for how the data is stored, so choose the one that best fits your architecture.